# invoke belongsTo return null laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

the tables in the database are
address
'address_type_id',
'address_type_id',
'line1',
'line2',
'line3',
'country',
'city',
'zip_code',
'other_detail',
'geo_location_id'

address type table
'address_type_id'
'address_type_name'

here is my models

```
public function Users(){
    return $this->hasOne('User','address_id');
}

public function Address_Type(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Address_Type','address_type_id','address_type_id');
}

public function Geo_Location(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Geo_Location','geo_location_id','geo_location_id');
}
```

}

```
public function Address(){
    return $this->hasMany('Address','address_type_id','address_type_id');
}
```

}

and in Controller
when i'm trying to get Address type like this

```
$address1=Address::find(1);

$geo=$address1->Geo_Location;
return Response::json(
    array(
        'error'   => false,
        'Address_Type' =>$address1->Address_Type),

    200
);
```

});
the result returns null

Comment: And the data in your db is correct? Meaning your address #1 references an existing record in `address_type`?

Comment: yes, of course, when i do like this address::with('Address_Type')->get(), it works very well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the naming of your relationship methods. When doing `$address1->Address_Type` this is what happens:

First, `__get()` in `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` is called, which proxies off to `getAttribute()`. In there it first checks for a few other things and then there's this:

```
$camelKey = camel_case($key);

if (method_exists($this, $camelKey))
{
    return $this->getRelationshipFromMethod($key, $camelKey);
}
```

As you can see the attribute name `Address_Type` get's converted into camelCase. It becomes `addressType`.

Now while PHP doesn't care if it's `AddressType` or `aDdReSsTyPe` an underscore makes a difference.

#### The solution

Change your relationship names. I suggest `addressType`, `geoLocation` but as I mentioned before, the only important thing is that you lose the `_`.